# Why can't CIVL verify OpenMP programs in my desktop?

Tags: openmp, formal-verification, model-checking

I installed CIVL in ubuntu 14.04 and want to use it to verify OpenMP programs, but I encountered some questions as following:
If I use the command 'civl verify file_name.c' to verify OpenMP, it just regard the OpenMP program as a common C program, because I missed a optional parameter '-ompNoSimplify'.
However, if I use the command 'civl verify -ompNoSimplify file_name.c', it cannot verify any OpenMP programs, even the very simple OpenMP programs. such as the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++)
        printf("%c\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

[the output of verification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUJaV.png)

Comment: There is a discussions in the google forum (the question is also proposed by me):  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/civl-users/59ivCWONGVg, but the question puzzled me is still unsolved, thank you for your help.